# String variable is not taking bulk number of characters

Tags: php, email, variables

I have written a demo php mailer function were i need to pass a variable which is **"$query_content"** in my code.

When it is given some small data (around 200 characters) it is displayed properly when i echo it, but when a data of more than 800 character its not taking in and not printed when i echo, even though data is completely stored in  database.

I heard that a variable can hold up to 2gb of data but in my case its not the same, please help me, pardon me if i went wrong somewhere, thank you.

**mailer.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
$to = $_POST['email'];
$query_content = $_POST['gst_query'];

$subject = 'GST Interactive posting alert!';
$message = 'Dear receiver,
There is a query posting in GST Interactive from  '. $_SESSION['fname'] .' as 

                                           '. $query_content .' 

To comment on the posting or to get connected with GST Interactive sign in with "http://www.something.com"
Regards
xyz team';


  /* echo   $query_content; */

$headers = 'From: '. $_SESSION['fname'] .'' . "\r\n" .
 'Reply-To: innovation@xyz.com' . "\r\n" .
  'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```

Comment: You should probably remove `echo $query_content`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you get $query_content from $_POST, so the problem could be in limitations of POST-request (in php.ini). Maybe big $query_content don't reach your script because of it's size.

Try to get $query_content in mailer.php from database, not from $_POST

Answer (score 0):

Your content is possibly too long for plain text email.

Try:

```php
$message = chunk_split(base64_encode($message));
$headers = 'From: ' . $_SESSION['fname'] . "\r\n" .
  'Reply-To: innovation@xyz.com' . "\r\n" .
  'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion() . "\r\n" .
  'Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64' . "\r\n\r\n";
```

Comment: Simply replace your current headers declaration/assignment with these lines. That should be enough.